# Div block hasn't free space for buttons

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

Div block hasn't free space for buttons in one line

I have a  block with a buttons, the buttons look good when 1920x1080 px but how to make adaptive buttons for 1080x720 and mobile platforms? Adaptive buttons will work in wordpress?

```css
.main_button_left {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 0px 15px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
  background: #ff6500;
  transition: 1s;
  border-color: #ff6500;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 150px;
}

.main_button {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 0px 15px 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ff6500;
  transition: 1s;
  border-color: #ff6500;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 150px;
}

button.main_button:hover,
button.main_button_right:hover,
button.main_button_left:hover {
  background: #ffcd07;
  border-color: #ffcd07;
}

.main_button_right {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 0px 15px 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ff6500;
  transition: 1s;
  border-color: #ff6500;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div class="main_panel">
    <button class="main_button_left">Button1</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button2</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button3</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button4</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button5</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button6</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button7</button>
    <button class="main_button_right">Button8</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flexbox for the buttons and set a minimum width. With media queries you can present them in a different way, depending on your requirements. When stacked, set the minimum width to 100%.

```css
button {
  color: white;
  background: #ff6500;
  border-color: #ff6500;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 0px 15px 0px;
  min-width: 70px;
  transition: 1s;
  width: 12%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.main_button_left {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}

button:hover {
  background: #ffcd07;
  border-color: #ffcd07;
}

.main_button_right {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.main_panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div class="main_panel">
    <button class="main_button_left">Button1</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button2</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button3</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button4</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button5</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button6</button>
    <button class="main_button">Button7</button>
    <button class="main_button_right">Button8</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

On small screen you can stack buttons vertically, or hide a menu and create a button, thats will show buttons.

Comment: have a tutorial about it? or how searc in English?

Comment: Search about "responsive menu css".

Comment: bardzo dziękuję